# Hough algorithm don't find outer circle when there is a circle inside

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I use hough transform to find circles in my picture, but it doesn't find outer circle.( I use opencv 2.4.2 and QT 3.3.0)

my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int  HoughCircle1()
{
    Mat src,dst, src_gray;

    /// Read the image
    src = imread("E:/imagesForImgProc/test.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if( !src.data )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /// Reduce the size of image
    Size size(src.cols/2,src.rows/2);
    resize(src, dst,size, 0, 0,  CV_INTER_LINEAR);

    /// Convert it to gray
    cvtColor( dst, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
    GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

    /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles( src_gray, circles,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );

   /// Draw the circles detected
   for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
   {
       Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
       int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
       /// circle center
       circle( dst, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
       /// circle outline
       circle( dst, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, 8, 0 );
   }

   /// Show your results
   namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", dst );
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HoughCircle1();
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

"Orginal image"
[image: Original image]

"Code result  "
[image: Code result]

"Wanted result"
[image: Wanted result]

Comment: Dupilicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885354/can-houghcircles-function-in-opencv-detect-circles-within-a-circle

Comment: Opencv implementation doesn't find concentric circles. There are workarounds described in other SO answers...

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32287930/5008845). Python code but can be easily ported to C++. Also, you can get good results on this image simply using a threshold and finding contours.